# Struts 2: how set a property value of a bean of an action using tags?

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a bean inside my action (here the code)

```java
public class FPFController extends ActionSupport{
    private FPFParameters fPFParameters;
    public FPFParameters getFPFParameters(){
        return fPFParameters;
    }
}


public class FPFParameters {
   private String strParameter;

   public void setStrParameter(String value) {
       this.strParameter = value;
   }

   public String getStrParameter() {
       return this.strParameter;
   }
}
```

and I need to set a property (strParameter) of this bean (fPFParameters) in a jsp: is it possible to do this using struts 2 tag or jstl tag?

Comment: Why would you want to set a value like this in the JSP itself?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***OGNL dot notation*** from Struts tags to access inner objects.

```
<s:textfield name="fPFParameters.strParameter" />
```

is equivalent to

```
getFPFParameters().setStrParameter(this.value)
```

Of course the set will be performed when the request will be sent; you need to communicate with the server to set a server value (a POST, a GET, an AJAX call etc).

If you want to set it without leaving the page, just bound an AJAX call to the `onchange` event of your object.

**EDIT**

---

The alternative to the use of `<jsp:useBean>` and `<jsp:setProperty>` in Struts2 is represented by the [Struts2 `<s:bean>` Tag](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/bean.html):

```
<s:bean name="foo.bar.FPFParameters" var="fPFParameters">
  <s:param name="strParameter">myValue</s:param>
</s:bean>

...

strParameter value is: 
<s:property value="#fPFParameters.strParameter" />
```

[Example of usage of `<s:bean>` tag](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-bean-tag-example/)

Comment: no, I need something like this `<jsp:setProperty name="fPFParameters" property="strParameter" value="value" />` with struts tag

Comment: the code you write create a new bean under a variable, but I want to take the bean I created before and I putted in request: How can I do?
I tried this, but it doesn't work

`<s:bean name="fi.fpf.mvc.FPFViewComponent" var="#request.viewComponent">
     <s:param name="#request.viewComponent.menuElement" value="value"/>
 
    </s:bean>`

Comment: That is exactly what `<jsp:useBean` and `<jsp:useProperty` does :/ create a new instance of a java bean from the JSP. It must not be that useful because I've never used that... now it would the right spot to clear what you are trying to achieve; if it is assigning a value to a property of a bean, so that once sent to the server it will be updated, then follow the first part of the answer; if it is reading an existing bean in JSP and updating its properties in the JSP to use them in the JSP, then... why ?! Just use `<s:set`

Comment: <s:set> I tried this <s:set var="#request.viewComponent.menuElement" value="#element" /> it works, the value is setted, but id doesn't invoke the method setMenuElement: it access to the property directly. There is a way to invoke the setter method?

Comment: Make your variable private; p.s the syntax your <s:set is strange :|

Comment: then they are not directly callable, the getters/setters will be used instead... again, take a step back and tell us what are you trying to achieve: I'm pretty sure there is a simpler, better way

Comment: no, no they are callable: I think that struts call the "setAccessible" method of reflection framework on the properties and then absign the values